# How to add hash file to Exploit Scanner plugin for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, exploit

While I have found the updated hash files to be added to WordPress, I have had a terrible time locating anything that gives specific direction as to where this file goes and exactly how to add it.  Should it be added via a single file created with notepad, or should it be placed in a folder?  I apologize if this sounds elementary, but this is a completely new adventure for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the hash values for the files are provided but the file itself has to be created with the name of the file it says it is missing.  Once that is created, move the file into the plugin itself and rerun the scan.